# Is it posible to open a cind of browse for file window to get the filepath of a file in c++?

Tags: c++

And if this is possible pleas explain how to do this.

Comment: Windows? Linux? MacOS? Do you use a GUI framework or directly the platform SDK?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a path and are on Windows, you probably want something like [SHBrowseForFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762115.aspx). If you are using a framework that abstracts away a lot of low-level Windows API stuff (MFC, Qt, WxWidgets, etc), then it may have some other more convenient function or class that does the same thing.

If you're not on Windows, then I can't help except by suggesting you search the operating system's API and/or the documentation of whatever GUI framework you use.